# Как вернуть значение через return?

Tags: javascript

```js
const products = [{
    name: 'Радар',
    price: 1300,
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'Сканер',
    price: 2700,
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'Дроид',
    price: 400,
    quantity: 7
  },
  {
    name: 'Захват',
    price: 1200,
    quantity: 9
  },
];

productName = []

function calculateTotalPrice(productName) {
  // Пиши код ниже этой строки

  let total = []
  for (const a of products) {
    if (products[0].name = a.name) {
      console.log(a);
      total.push(a.price * a.quantity)
    }

  }
  console.log('-----------');
  console.log(total);
  console.log('------------');
  return total

  // Пиши код выше этой строки
}
calculateTotalPrice(productName)
```

как сделать чтобы return total возвращал тот же результат что и console.log(total)

Comment: А что именно вас интересует?

Comment: Непонятно чего вам нужно. Он и так возвращает total.

Comment: @AzizUmarov мне надо чтобы я в консоле увидел результат return total он мне покажет или только через console.log смогу увидеть, я честно говоря уже запутался

Comment: Вам итоговая сумма нужна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function calculateTotalPrice(productName) {
  let total = products.reduce((t,i) => t + (i.name == productName)? i.price * i.quantity : 0, 0);
  return total;
}
console.log(calculateTotalPrice('Сканер'));
```

---

```
function calculateTotalPrice(productName) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if (products[i].name == productName)
      total += products[i].price * products[i].quantity;
  }
  return total;
}
console.log(calculateTotalPrice('Сканер'));
```

Comment: Игорь, Вы меня извините, я уверен, что Ваш код будет работать, как уже показала практика сегодняшняя, но я еще не понимаю этот синтаксис - очень профессионально для меня, можете более простым синтаксисом обьяснить? спасибо

Comment: чудесно, спасибо огромное, переделал через for of и благодаря Вам понял в чем ошибки делаю четвертый день, еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
let total = 0
  for (const a of products) {
    if (a.name === productName)
      total+=a.price*a.quantity 
    
  }
  return total
```